# Detect change in window language and change language of Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I wanted to detect the change in the window language. I can know the current language using `app.getSystemLocale()` in the main file of the electron. But I don't know how to auto-detect that the Windows language has been changed so based on that I may change the application language.

I tried searching for this in the documentation but didn't find anything.